# How to get the array of touch position in iphone without using event?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, cocos2d-iphone

Is it possible to get the array of touches positions from the screen without getting it from touch events?? If there were no touches in the screen the array would be empty. Any idea??

If there's a cocos2d method for this, would solve too...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to get 'out of band' touches in CocoaTouch. I am unsure if Cocos keeps the information around that would be required to do this, but if it doesn't it wouldn't be that hard to track current touches and what state they're in.